# Checking if the user is online in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I am beginner in Laravel. I use Laravel 5.8 in my project.
I have this Model:

```
class User extends Authenticatable implements MustVerifyEmail
{
    use Notifiable;
    public static $roles = [];


    protected $fillable = ['last_activity', 'enable', 'name', 'surname', 'email', 'email_verified_at', 'password', 'counter', 'url_address', 'isCompany', 'isMailing'];


    protected $hidden = [
        'password', 'remember_token',
    ];

    public function roles()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Role');
    }

    public function mainRole()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('App\Role');
    }

    public function comments()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Comments');
    }


    public function hasRole(array $roles)
    {

        foreach ($roles as $role) {

            if (isset(self::$roles[$role])) {
                if (self::$roles[$role]) return true;

            } else {
                self::$roles[$role] = $this->roles()->where('name', $role)->exists();
                if (self::$roles[$role]) return true;
            }

        }
        return false;
    }

    public function loginHistory()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\UserLoginHistory');
    }

    public function companies()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Companies', 'company_id');
    }


    public function images()
    {
        return $this->hasManyThrough('App\UploadedFiles', 'App\User', 'id', 'photoable_id');
    }


    public function scopeOfRoleType($query, $types)
    {
        return $query->whereHas('roles', function ($q) use ($types) {
            $q->whereIn('name', $types);
        });
    }



}
```

In last_activity - I have date for example 2019-07-16 10:26:12

I need show on my twig page:

```
@foreach ($usersList as $user)
User name: $user->name is now ...... (offline or online)

@endforeach
```

I would like to see if the user is online or offline.

I think about something like this:

```
public function isOnline()
        {
            return .....
        }
```

but I do not know how to check this activity :(

Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends how you would define being online. Http is a stateless protocol.

You could however define being online as being active within the last five minutes. This way you can implement the function like this:

```php
public function isOnline(): bool
{
    return $this->last_activity->gt(Carbon\Carbon::now()->subMinutes(5));
}
```

also make sure to tag last_activity as a date:

```php
protected $dates = ['last_activity'];
```

As your appliation grows I would think about another solution instead of loading all users from the database into memory.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose by "online" you mean using the website and interacting with it.
You'll have to decide a time interval in which the user can be considered either "online", or "offline" and not interacting anymore. Maybe... 10 minutes?
Compare the "last activity" field with current time, to see if they are active or not. Use for exmaple **Carbon::now()** to get current time and compare.